# Возможно ли на Chart.js сделать такой же таймлайн как у GoogleCharts?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, timeline

Возможно ли на Chart.js сделать такой же таймлайн как у GoogleCharts?

Нужно использовать `type: horizontalBar`, и время (+- 12 часов от текущего) по оси X.

Пример из GoogleCharts: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline

Comment: такую штуку можно и вообще без chart.js сделать с точно таким же эффектом

Comment: там позиционируется выпадашки от top а инфу подтянуть с json/xml откуда угодно хоть с txt